# file is not getting passed as an input

Tags: java, smartxls

I'm getting `NullPointerException` upon passing a `.xlsb` file to a method. It seems that file is not getting selected but the file exists in that folder. Please advise

```
public class readxlsb {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            String fileName1 ="C:\\abc\\TULDUBINV_EX_10768148_1.xlsb";
            com.smartxls.WorkBook wb = new com.smartxls.WorkBook();

            System.out.println(wb);
            wb.readXLSB(fileName1);
            System.out.println(wb);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The constructor of the API have the following methods:

```
public void readXLSB(String filename) throws Exception {
    this.a.q(filename);
}

public void readXLSB(InputStream in) throws Exception {
    this.a.d(in);
}

public void readXLSB(InputStream in, String pass) throws Exception {
    this.a.a(in, pass);
}
```

Comment: You might start and tell us _where_ you get that NPE (and probably debug yourself what exactly is null and why) - just saying.

Comment: You think the file exists, but does Java? Is `new File(fileName1).exists()` true?

Comment: @Thomas on line wb.readXLSB(fileName1); i am getting an exception

Comment: I'd guess the exception is thrown somewhere _inside_ the method that is called at that line. So either you step into that method with a debugger (normally you should get sources for the libs you use) or post a stracktrace here.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use jxl.Workbook, it's much easier and comprehensive. I have worked with jxl and highly rely on it. Use like-`Workbook workBook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("C:\\abc\\TULDUBINV_EX_10768148_1.xlsb"));
        Sheet sheet = workBook.getSheet(0);`

Comment: I forgot you reading .xlsb file, might be jxl does'nt support that format. For xlsb you can use Smartxls api. Use like--`workBook.readXLSB(new java.io.FileInputStream("template.xlsb"));`

Comment: Well smartxls is not free I am looking for open source

Comment: which api you currently using?

Comment: Smartxls but it is not free please advise any way through which I can convert. Xlsb file to. Xls or xlsx,  any way in Java that will be really appreciated

Comment: You can convert it to .xls via microsoft excel. After opening your .xlsb file, click **save as** and choose your option from the **save as type** list

Comment: Well I have to do the same thing programmatically, please advise how to achieve the same

Comment: After converting it to xls you can then use jxl api

Comment: Thanks but first please advise how programmatically I will convert. Xlsb to. Xls

Comment: Also smartxls working. Why not it worked in your case. Check the file path you gave is correct and file exist in that path.

Comment: Why you want to convert it with code while you can simply do it with online converter or with microsoft excel

Comment: Well smart xls now worked in your case I have a requirement like this when I have to read all excels file programmatically., that I am already doing g through poi but please advise for xlsb

Comment: That's what i said, smartxls is able to read xlsb files, then what's the problem in reading xlsb?

Comment: The problem is that it is paid API and I am looking for open source one

Comment: Download the jar as i did, i did'nt ask for money there

Comment: Well that is evaluation version means it will be there for few days so the best way can you please advise if I can decompile and create the same jar something like that

Comment: Well you can use the following commands:  unjar  `jar -xvf abc.jar `  jar  `jar cf abc.jar input-files`

Comment: Then only I will get class files well can you please advise how can I create a new java project that will have same java files which they have use so that later on I can create jar of my own project

Comment: You will need a decompiler then copy-paste all classes files as in same subfolder structure.

Comment: Well in this jar if you please open it you can see there are at least 80 class files so don't you think this will be a big effort

Comment: Well you have to do it if you fear to be paid. Create a new project on eclipse ide and include SX.jar in build path. You'll needed jadclipse plugin as well. Then seeing the jar package structure create same your package structure and in same ways all classes. What you need to do is open respective .class file, copy code and paste in respective your java class. I know its cumbersome task but better to be paid.

Comment: Thanks for the advise but will all the reference dependencies will be solved in that case I mean all the interdependencies of different classes